# Use fit_resamples with custom split data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidymodels

I have a custom function that splits my data into training and testing sets based on various criteria and rules. I'd like to use this function in a tidymodels workflow together with `fit_resamples`. However, when I can make my list look like a list made with `vfold_cv`, it does not seem to work. The example code I am using:

```
data(ames, package = "modeldata")

split_data <- function(df, n) {
  set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
  df$id <- seq.int(nrow(df))
  list_of_splits <- list()
  
  for(i in 1:n) {
    train_index <- sample(df$id, size=ceiling(nrow(df)*.8))
    train_set <- df[train_index,]
    test_set <- df[-train_index,]
    list_of_splits[[i]] <- list(train_set = train_set, test_set = test_set)
  }
  
  return(list_of_splits)
}

splits <- split_data(ames, 5)

resamples <- map(splits, ~rsample::make_splits(
  x = .$train_set |> select(colnames(.$test_set)),
  assessment = .$test_set
))

names(resamples) <- paste0("Fold", seq_along(resamples))

resamples <- tibble::tibble(splits = resamples,
                            id = names(resamples))

lm_model <- 
  linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm")

lm_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(lm_model) %>%
  add_formula(Sale_Price ~ Longitude + Latitude)

res <- lm_wflow %>%
  fit_resamples(resamples = resamples)
```

The error returned after running that last line is:

```
Error in `check_rset()`:
! The `resamples` argument should be an 'rset' object, such as the type produced by `vfold_cv()` or other 'rsample' functions.
```

If I try to force the class to be "rset" `class(resamples) <- "rset"`, the list no longer looks correct and I get the same error.

What is the correct method of using a custom crossfold data set?

Note - additional question: In the example code above, the test and training set size is consistent across folds. In my actual data, this will vary slightly - does this matter at all?

Comment: Please do **not** update the question to include the answer; post a self-answer in the answer space below instead

Comment: I've rolled back your edit adding an answer in your Question. I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own Answer). When you've solved the problem yourself, [posting an answer to your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Comment: The source Markdown for the answer which you included in you question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1b887b62-bc39-48e1-ad7e-009931fc36ca/view-source). Please feel free to use that in order to create an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like [`rsample::manual_rset()`](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/manual_rset.html) might do what you want?

Comment: Thanks. That worked and I was able to get it working with my primary data. Will update solution above

Answer (score 0):

**Solution based on @hannahfrick's answer above:**

```
data(ames, package = "modeldata")

split_data <- function(df, n) {
  set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
  df$id <- seq.int(nrow(df))
  list_of_splits <- list()
  
  for(i in 1:n) {
    train_index <- sample(df$id, size=ceiling(nrow(df)*.8))
    train_set <- df[train_index,]
    test_set <- df[-train_index,]
    list_of_splits[[i]] <- list(train_set = train_set, test_set = test_set)
  }
  
  return(list_of_splits)
}

splits <- split_data(ames, 5)

resamples <- map(splits, ~list(
  analysis = .$train_set |> select(colnames(.$test_set)) |> pull(id),
  assessment = .$test_set$id
))

splits <- lapply(resamples, make_splits, data = ames)

final_split <- manual_rset(splits, paste("Split", seq(1:5)))

lm_model <- 
  linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm")

lm_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(lm_model) %>%
  add_formula(Sale_Price ~ Longitude + Latitude)

res <- lm_wflow %>%
  fit_resamples(resamples = final_split)

collect_metrics(res)
```